# Do all $x$ in Hilbert space $H$ equal $U T \eta$ for some $T \in R$ and unitary $U \in R'$, when $\eta$ is separating for $R$?

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space on which von Neumann algebra $R$ acts; let $\eta \in H$ be a separating vector for $R$ (i.e. the zero operator is the only $T \in R$ such that $T \eta = 0$); let $R'$ denote $R$'s commutant as usual.

Is it true that for all $x \in H$, $x = U T \eta$  for some $T \in R$ and **unitary** $U \in R'$? [Note -- I should stress I'm requiring $T$ to be in $R$ itself, and $U$ to be in $R$'s commutant.]

I know the answer is yes [even if $T$ is further required to be the identity operator] if $U$ is allowed to be an arbitrary member of $R'$, since $\eta$'s being separating for $R$ entails that it is cyclic for $R'$. But I'm wondering if this statement about unitary $U \in R'$ holds. Thanks!

Comment: Does it not suffice to consider the polar decomposition?

Comment: I'm not seeing how to directly apply that ... my final comment might have mistakenly suggested that I'm looking for $T$ and $U$ both in the commutant ($R'$) in which case using polar decomposition would immediately give a "yes" answer to my question ...  I should have stressed that I'm requiring $T$ to be in $R$ itself, but $U$ to be in its commutant ($R'$).

Comment: Aha! My mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure why $\overline{R'\eta}=H$ implies the last paragraph?
$R'\eta$ is already closed?